# Join 3 tables in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

I have 3 tables I am trying to join.

```
user 
photographer
gallery
```

They all share the same identifier column user_id.

When I do a select, there is one record in the user table, one record in the photographer table and currently 5 records in the gallery table.

I would like to retrieve just one row back, but containing the 5 results out of the gallery table.

I tried the following but it returned 5 separate rows.

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('photographer', 'gallery.user_id = photographer.user_id');
$this->db->join('gallery', 'gallery.user_id = users.id');
```

Basically, every photographer has a user entry, but they may have multiple images stored in the gallery table.

I only require one result per photographer, but need the 5 images too.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you use $this->db->limit(1); ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options as I see it:

1. Use 2 queries: one for the tables user and photographer where it will return only one record and the second query to retrieve the images.
2. Leave the query as it is and list the user + photographer from the first row and loop all the rows to list the images.

**Note:** I prefer using the first method, although it adds more queries to my application, but this way it's very clear what I have intended and other programmers will find it easier to modify my script.

Comment: Agreed, he should definately use 2 queries!